# django jsonfield save to the database

Tags: python, database, django, json

I have a Django model that uses a JsonField field.

In some point, I update the field with an IP address, and save that field:

```
class Agent(models.Model):
    properties = jsonfield.JSONField(default = {})

def save_ip_address(self, ip_address):
    self.properties['ip'] = ip_address
    self.save()
```

Looks pretty straight forward.. isn't it?

But the field wasn't saved with the ip dictionary item... and I have no idea why!

I did a workaround that works but doesn't look good in my code:

```
d = self.properties
d['ip'] = ip_address
self.properties = d 
self.save()
```

This way the JsonField is indeed being saved in the database with the IP address.

Does anyone know why the first approach didn't work? and what should I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Added my model to the question

Comment: show your idea is to catch the ip_address and save it ?

Comment: Yes.. and then in another action, when there is no IP address, I want to go to that dictionary and pull the last known IP

Comment: there is an [ip address field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ipaddressfield)

Comment: I can use that ip address field... but in the future I would like to add another property and the problem will be the same...

Comment: Is your indentation correct? Your method is outside of the class.

Comment: Yep.. wish that was my problem!!

Comment: careful when calling `save()` inside your model methods - if you save an older reference to the instance, it can overrwrite your changes inside the method - better to save the instance explicitly after calling the attr setter

Answer (score 2):

Your example worked just fine for me when I tried it. Could you elaborate on what you mean by the field wasn't saved? To clarify I am testing in the console. Created an app with your model in it, opened the django console and ran:

```
>>> from test_app.models import Agent
>>> a = Agent()
>>> a.properties = {"host": "test"}
>>> a.save()
>>> a.properties
{'host': 'test'}
>>> a.save_ip_address("127.0.0.1")
>>> a.properties
{'ip': '127.0.0.1', 'host': 'test'}
```

Can you recreate those steps to the same effect? If so the bug is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: My Properties field was {'host' : 'test'}. Then I saved and it was {'ip' : '127.0.0.1', 'host' : 'test'}. But my database remain only with {'host' : 'test'}, so next time I ran this I had no 'ip' in my field.

Comment: Still works just fine for me even with previous properties in the JSONField. Are you testing this using the django console or in an actual part (a view, say) of your app? If the latter could you post the code for it.

Comment: I agree with you that a.properties changes even in the first example. I can see the 'ip' : '127.0.0.1' in the debugger. It just doesn't save in the database, so next time I open the page I don't have it in my properties...

Comment: Have you tried it exactly the way I did, with the django console?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36008/discussion-between-pete-tinkler-and-tidharpeer)

Comment: I have a similar issue. Sometimes data is saved in the JSONField, sometime is not. I'm using django 2.1 and postgres-11.3